# Slow Windows booting and Performance

Tags: windows-10, performance

My system configuration is the following:

```
Processor: Intel Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @1.80GZ 2.40GZ
RAM: 16.0 GB (14.8 GB usable)
System TYpe: x64-based processor.
```

I'm using Dell Inspirion. Running on Windows 10 and is just 2 years old. The age didn't affect the performance drastically.

But the system booting, performance is extremely slow. I don't know how I can capture "slowness" in any metric. So not putting it here.

My question is why my system is slow, even though I've very good specifications? And how I can improve the performance?

**Edit:**

Please find the screenshot of startup:

[image]

**Edit**

[image: Dell System Test Result:]

Dell Hardware Test:

[image]

Resource Monitor:

[image]
System Report

Comment: Please edit your question and post all programs running on boot: right-click on the Start button (the Windows logo in the bottom-left corner) and choose Task Manager from the menu which appears. Select 'More details' and then 'start-up' tab. Upload a screenshot if you can.

Comment: @Santeador: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my question with your suggestion.

Comment: Have you passed any hardware test? I'll start with Memtest for a few hours.

Comment: Well, you can simply pass Dell Diag: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN114988

Comment: @Santeador: No. I don't know about these test. So never did it. Let me try them and post the result here. THanks a lot!

Comment: I'll wait for it ;-)

Comment: @Santeador: I've added the test result. I went through Dell tests as Memtest seems to take quite a long time.

Comment: What are your resource monitor saying? (Make a custom report). As for booting, do you have fast-boot enabled, or disabled?

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow: Thanks Michael for your comment. My fast-boot is enabled. I'm running few more diagnosis check I found following Santeador link. After completion of all those diagnosis test. I'll update my question. Thanks again!

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU Usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: have you captured the trace? Otherwise we can't help you

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thanks for your comments. I had some hard time installing WPT. But I can run the test only tomorrow as it's pretty late for me here. Once done, I'll upload the file. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @magicandre1981: I've uploaded the file after running WPT as you have suggested. The file size (without zip is over 1 GB). But I tried to  open using Event Viewer. But I can't see anything in those files. Please let me know if I did anything wrong.

Comment: It's in "System Report" link.

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow: I've also added the "Resource Monitor" screenshot. I also ran the extensive Dell performance test. My system passed all the tests. I need to update couple of drivers, which I did.

Comment: Do your specs are good, and your resource usage isn't too bad. We've confirmed there are no errors with disk and/or ram, so apart from that I'd suggest: 'sfc.exe /scannow' as Admin via CMD and then potentially editing your start up services to manual (make a list of what you do so you can revert).

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow: I found this result after running "sfc.exe /scannow": "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

Comment: I've posted what I saw from the trace. your WD drive is simply slow as hell. replace it with a SSD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After I loaded the ETL into WPA.exe, I clicked on `Profile`-> `Apply`, "`browse catalog`" and select the file `FullBoot.Boot.wpaprofile` I saw this overview

[image]

Boot to desktop is done in 79 seconds, and Winlogon-Phase and ExplorerInit are slow:

> **What Happens in This Subphase** 
>   The WinLogonInit subphase begins when SMSSInit completes and starts Winlogon.exe. During WinLogonInit,
>   the user logon screen appears, the service control manager starts
>   services, and Group Policy scripts run. WinLogonInit ends when the
>   Explorer process starts.
>
> **Visual Cues** WinLogonInit begins shortly before the logon screen appears. It ends just before the desktop appears for the first time.
>
> **WinLogonInit Performance Vulnerabilities** Many operations occur in parallel during WinLogonInit. On many systems, this subphase is CPU
>   bound and has large I/O demands. Good citizenship from the services
>   that start in this phase is critical for optimized boot times.
>       Services can declare dependencies or use load order groups to ensure that they start in a specific order. Windows processes load
>   order groups in serial order. **Service initialization delays in an
>   early load order group block subsequent load order groups and can
>   possibly block the boot process** .

```
ExplorerInit Subphase
```

**What Happens in This Subphase**

> The ExplorerInit subphase begins when Explorer.exe starts. During
>   ExplorerInit, the system creates the desktop window manager (DWM)
>   process, which initializes the desktop and displays it for the first
>   time. This phase is CPU intensive. The initialization of DWM and
>   desktop occurs in the foreground, while in the background the service
>   control manager (SCM) starts services and the memory manager
>   prefetches code and data. On most systems ExplorerInit is CPU bound,
>   and timing issues are likely the result of a simple resource
>   bottleneck.
>   **Visual Cues** 
> ExplorerInit begins just before the desktop appears for the first time. There is no clear visual cue to indicate the end
>   of ExplorerInit.

Looking at the CPU Usage (Sampled) shows no bottleneck:

[image]

so, check the disk and here you have the bootleneck of the system:

[image]

As you can see the disk is most of the time complete busy. [Your WDC WD10JPVX-75JC3T0 is a 5400rpm drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QJIUJE4) which is not fast to handle all IO requests that occur during boot and later starting all startup tools.

You can do a temporary [speedup of boot with xbootmgr](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140262), but to fix the slowness replace the ugly slow WD drive with a SSD like the `Samsung 850 EVO`

Comment: Thanks a lot magicandre1981! You put the answer with great clarity. I'll  change into SSD. Thank you again!

Comment: Beautifully written answer. The best part is from next time I can follow these steps to check the resources myself. So very resourceful answer as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As this seems to be an ongoing thread, I will convert my comments into a unified "answer" as I believe some of the steps will assist others experiencing this fault.

This section will cover testing hardware issues:

**Testing your Hard-Drive and SSD for Defects**

Of course, you can use command-line to perform basic tests:

`chkdsk.exe /R /X` - R implies you use /F - fix errors on disk and locate bad sectors.

As specified, for your specific device you can use the dell Desktop client, or [Quick Scan](http://www.dell.com/support/home/au/en/aubsdt1/quicktest):

> The Quick Test scans the hard drive, memory, processor and disc drive of your Windows-based PC or tablet for errors.

Otherwise, you can use the [Windows Error Checking Tool](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/).

**Test your RAM**

Open an elevated command prompt and run the following command:

`mdsched.exe`

This will test your RAM on your next PC boot.

**System Integrity**

Run the following command and it will identify if you have any 'System Integrity Violations':

`sfc.exe /scannow`

There are, of course, third party tools you can check:

1. [Advanced System Care](http://www.iobit.com/en/advancedsystemcarefree.php)
2. [Auslogic Boost Speed](http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/boost-speed/)
3. [Iolo System Mechanic 12](http://www.iolo.com/resources/articles/whats-new-in-system-mechanic-12/)

Note: These tools all act differently, and I would **suggest** you not use them in unison.

**Windows Perfomance Toolkit**

As mentioned by [MagicAndre191](https://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981), install the Windows Performance Toolkit, explicitly [WPRUI](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2012/11/23/wpt-installing-the-windows-performance-toolkit-v5-0-wprui-wpr-xperf/).

I will not go into detail, [but you can look at this tool in detail (to an extent) from TechNet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2013/03/22/troubleshooting-windows-performance-issues-using-the-windows-performance-recorder/).

**Uninstall Redundant Apps and Services**

As advised, stop apps from starting:

1. Right click on your taskbar
2. Click Task Manager
3. Locate the Startup Tab
4. Right click and disable useless apps

Then, I would suggest setting services to manual, or even disabled.

Here is a [small list of services that are "Safe to disable"](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/which-windows-services-are-safe-disable-when). If you are not sure how to do this, [read this blog](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2495-services-start-disable.html).

Things such as defragging your registry, cleaning redundant files from registry and your PC *may slightly improve* your performance as well.

*This answer will be updated as we go along.*

Comment: totally crap answer with useless advices * facepalm*

Comment: @Michael: THanks for your answer. I'll try to follow your instructions.