# Microsoft KB3000850 slows down Windows 8.1 logon process significantly

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I've got an absolutely fresh Windows 8.1 Pro x64 English UEFI which seems to work smoothly.

First of all, the preinstalled Windows Update client doesn't work at all today - just checking for updates for ages - until KB3138615 is installed.

When I am finally able to check for updates it appears that there are about 300 updates available with **KB3000850** November 2014 update rollup among them, which requests **KB2919355** already installed and forces to download **KB3003057** and **KB3014442** as it requires them also.

As at the moment I know nothing about KB3000850's craftiness I just select all the available updates and wait a couple of hours until the update process finished.

When my PC is ready I notice that the Welcome screen now takes **16 times longer** (24 turns of welcome circle after vs 1.5 before) and there is **2 minutes 30 seconds of black colored emptiness** between the Welcome Screen and the desktop appearance.

After some research I've found out that both delays are caused by KB3000850.

When I've downloaded each required update to install KB3000850 then no matter if I restart my PC after each update required by KB3000850 (including KB3000850 itself) or install them all during the same session I have the delays.

Also seems that installing all available updates through Windows Update doesn't solve the problem.

Delays appear each time I turn on or restart my PC when KB3000850 is installed.

Additionally I can no longer install KB3138615 after KB3000850. In this case KB3138615's standalone installer behaves exactly like Windows Update before applying KB3138615 - it endlessly checks the computer for installed updates.

How can I reduce the time taken by the logon process? I appreciate any suggestion other than "ignore KB3000850."

(I've researched a lot before asking, but the only troubles connected to KB3000850 were related to different kinds of crashes after applying this patch.)

**The question:** How can I get rid of that ~3 minutes pause between the logon screen and desktop appearance?

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk and also works for Windows 8.1), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, under  Resource select **CPU usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll analyze what is slow.

Comment: Here is the log: http://www.filedropper.com/wpr. WPRUI was recording data over the 2,5 munute black screen. It is also possible to move mouse pointer and ctrl+alt+del during the black screen period.

Comment: I see no delay. boot is done in 8s

Comment: + 24 turns of the Welcome circle and + 2,5 minutes of black screen each time the PC boots :)

Comment: I can only tell you what I see in the trace. Here welcome is fast

Comment: I posted how you see how long boot takes. Capture several traces until you see the delay in the trace. WPA shows which part under Welcome (Winlogon-Phase) is slow

Answer (score 1):

Load the ETL into WPA.exe, [load the debug symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448108.aspx), click on `Profile`->`Apply`, `browse catalog` and select the file `FullBoot.Boot.wpaprofile`. Now you see an overview on how long Windows boots:

[image]

In the ETL it shows 8.8s for full boot.

Capture several traces and analyze them as I described here. Maybe sometimes you see the slowness in the trace.

Comment: Thanks for the research, really. I've stopped with MSDN image of Windows 8.1 Pro U3 - it has accepted the product ID embedded into my PC and seems to work fine. At the same time Windows 8.1 Pro U3 available for the end users at the Microsoft site ends up with endless black screen immediately after the installation.

Comment: As for the 8,8 seconds boot time of my U1 upgraded to U3, I believe it boots normally but something takes 2,5 minutes after the boot is finished - I can move the mouse pointer during the black screen period and WPR interface appeared over that black screen also. I suppose it is something like "why not you try Windows 10 instead? it is better and there is no 2,5 minutes delay in Windows 10!" message from the Microsoft.

Comment: after boot is a different thing. you ask for 2.5m delay at logon.2.5m after boot is startup issue. reduce the number of tool that you run automatically during logon.

Comment: reading question before making answer is a good practice. Just to let you know.

Comment: I did, but you have no idea what you talk about. I've analyzed thounds of boot issues and now how Windwos works. according to your question you see a delay at winlogon-explorerInit, but the trace shows no issue. I'm out here, I don't discuss with trolls like you any longer.

Comment: if I had any idea then I wouldn't ask. And thank you for downvoting )

Comment: you violate rules by asking question that [I already answered some time ago](https://superuser.com/a/1159565/174557). Here I explained in detail what happens. if you would do a search you would find that reply. So no research effort from your side, so downvote. that are the rules here.

Comment: In spite of the fact I've spent a couple of months researching, I would never find that question and your answer just because the problem you are referring to is absolutely different and moreover it is related to Windows 10. But if your crown and self-conceit advise you that slowdown on Windows 10 equals 2,5 minutes pause on Windows 8.1 then I'm terribly sorry I haven't guess that I must search for Windows 10 when experiencing problems with Windows 8.1.

Comment: @YKKY - You shouldn't about a downvotes, a single upvote, can counter 5 downvotes.  So instead of being annoyed about a single downvote, take steps to improve your question, and go for the upvotes.

Comment: @Ramhound, I don't care about my rating at all, I just expect useful answers instead of plain showoffing while ignoring the question. ) Thanks for kind words anyway!

Comment: @Ramhound, he can edit the question 1000 times, it won't help. we have **no** crystal ball to see what happens on his system, so we will be never able to answer it. I told him how to trace/analyze the issue, but he only trolls around.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I actually realize that, but feel obligated to give advice all the same and persaude him into improving his question.